# Sharing app content between portals using 2Sxc

Tags: 2sxc, dnn9

I need to design a content system similar to the news article 2sxc application. However, in my situation I have a primary subdomain and multiple secondary subdomains each of which is a portal in a single install of DNN.  I need the primary to be able to selectively share articles with the secondary subdomains. I also need the secondary subdomains to be able to have their own articles. I have explored creating a ghost content type on the secondary sites, but this doesn't seem to share the content.  I have used the visual query designer with an App Data Source to pull data from the zone and app of the primary. Using this, I can pull the needed article data, however, it also pulls lots of meta data like the name of each field on the content type etc.  So I assumed I could filter this stream by content type, but when I do that it removes all items in the stream. Additionally, I have tried using razor code to get the correct data, but have been unsuccessful. So:

1. What is the best way to accomplish sharing the articles as described?
2. What am I missing on the visual query designer that is causing it to filter all results when filtering by type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, for 2, you are using the [App Datasource](https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Eav.DataSources.App.html). In the docs (linked), have a look at the first screenshot and the note above it. By renaming the streams coming out of the source, you automatically filter on the CT.

And for 1, I do agree that using Queries seems like a great choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more options to achieve this BTW

1. You can just show a module of Portal 1 on Portal 2 using Dnn features to share modules
2. Use the mechanics described by @Jeremy in his answer
3. 2sxc 13.2 will offer a new shared-global-app system which is actually meant for other scenarios, but could also be used here.
4. You could also provide the data on your primary site as a RSS or WebService, and re-use that on the target site

Comment: I was looking in to Shared Apps recently, for the first time. I found this post which lead me to realizing it had become a Patron-paid feature at 50 credits per month. So, two things, 1) is there documentation on this somewhere or a demo or a blog? and 2) I noticed in the Patron features there is a trial, but its only 24 hours. I hope you realize that is an awkwardly short time-frame. Testing and experimenting, especially when it involves multiple stake holders and the client can take days. Please consider upping the trial to 14 days?

Comment: The shared Apps are actually a new feature that never existed before. So they have only ever been patron only. Docs are still fairly incomplete as most enterprise customers need some coaching to get it modeled. If you're interested, best contact me directly so I can guide you. In terms of testing: Since even patron contributions are on a monthly basis, you can just license it for a month. The cost isn't very high compared to the cost of your time, so there will be some budget available :)